# ui router nested view not showing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i'm using ui-router, and when i change to state neat.home.patientDashboard the view patientBoard does not get replaced with the one in the parent state, so the it keeps the same view. I try to change state when an item of the table in patientTable.html is clicked.

Also, i want to take the url field in the home state, but if i take it the view doesn't display.

I'm kind of new in AngularJS, so if there's something i'm not doing according to standards or something i apologize.

If somebody could help me with this it would be great since i've stuck in this for a day now.

Thanks

neat.js:

```
angular.module('neat', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/views/dataBoard.html',
                controller: 'BaseController'
            })
            .state('home.board', {
                views: {
                    'patientBoard' : {
                        templateUrl: '/views/patient/patientTable.html',
                        controller: 'PatientTableController'
                    },
                    'messageBoard' : {
                        templateUrl: '/views/messageBoard.html',
                        controller: 'MessageBoardController'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('home.board.patientDashboard', {
                views: {
                    'patientBoard@' : {
                        templateUrl: '/views/patient/patientDashboard.html',
                        controller: 'PatientDashboardController'
                    }
                }
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    });
```

Here's a sample of the HTML:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>NEAT</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../lib/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
        <script src="../lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../lib/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../lib/angularJS/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../lib/angularJS/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/neat.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/controllers/baseController.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/controllers/patientTableController.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/controllers/patientDashboardController.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/controllers/patientInfoController.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/controllers/messageBoardController.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="neat">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

dataBoard.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid board">
    <div class="row">
        <div ui-view="patientBoard" class="col-sm-8"></div>
        <div ui-view="messageBoard" class="col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

patientTable.html

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
        </tr>
        <tr  ng-repeat="patient in patientsCollection.items">
            <td>
                <a ui-sref="home.board.patientDashboard">{{patient.data[1].value}}</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm your last route `home.board.patientDashboard` is in another view, you should add another tag `ui-view` to display it, or rename your `$state` so you don't add another view.